# Cannot display Contact.Email in the Search Layout of a Contact lookup - cannot find any documentation that specifies this limitation

Tags: configuration, sales-cloud

1. Let's say we have multiple contacts with the same name and linked to the same account (these are not duplicate contacts, they are genuinely the same name and against the same company).
2. To make it very easy for users to identify the *correct* contact to link, it is helpful to display Contact.Email in the default Contact search layout such that any record being created/updated can display the email address; which will be unique. This would allow users to choose the *correct* contact.
3. The search layout configuration below does *not* show the Contact.Email:

[image]

as this results in:

[image]

4. However, if I created a simple Contact formula that displays the Contact.Email and add that to the Contact search layout like so:

[image]

then this indeed does display the contact email value in the contact lookup fields across the org:

[image]

**Question:** I cannot find any documentation which speaks to this limitation on Contact.Email (that it cannot be displayed in Contact search layouts for lookups in Lightning Experience). Does any documentation exist or is this a known issue on the IdeaExchange (again, I cannot find this anywhere).